# WebSphere wsadmin: Override Session Management For Specific Web Module in Application

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a WebSphere application called "Acme" which has 4 Web Modules ("acme1", "acme2", "acme3" and "acme4". I need to do the following for **ONLY** acme2, i.e only one of the 4 web modules.

- Override the session management.
- Disable "Set session cookies to HTTP Only to help prevent cross-site scripting attacks"

So, far I've only figured out how to override the session management at the application level through the below snippet, but not at the webmodule level.

```
application = AdminConfig.getid('/Deployment:Acme/')
mainObject = AdminConfig.showAttribute(application, 'deployedObject')
SessionManagerAttrs = [['sessionManagement', [['enable', 'true'], ['defaultCookieSettings', [['path','/'], ['useContextRootAsPath', 'false'], ['name', 'JSESSIONID'], ['httpOnly', 'false']]]]]]

AdminConfig.create('ApplicationConfig', mainObject, SessionManagerAttrs)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[This IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_webmodules.html) explains how to set session management attributes at the web module level using wsadmin scripting.